# WPF ComboBox with custom ItemSource binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

In my app I have a lot of `ComboBox` with item list predefined by users. I do not want add all lists on my ViewModel (maybe I'm wrong). I prefer to add an additional parameter to the MyComboBox control (new control which inherit from the `ComboBox`) with the id of list which I want load from database. E.g.:

```
<MyComboBox ItemsSourceId = "SAMPLE_ID" SelectedItem = "{Binding valueCode}" />
```

In behind code I will execute query and bind results to `ItemSource`.

```
SELECT itemCode, itemValue FROM UserDictionaries WHERE itemListCode = 'SAMPLE_ID'
```

It is good or bad idea? Maybe you have some sample code? ;)

Advantages of the solution: cleaner ViewModel. Disadvantages: database context in control.

Comment: will the 'list ID' change during run-time?

Comment: list ID (in my example SAMPLE_ID) is const.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to put it in the `ViewModel`? This is exactly what the `ViewModel` is for. If you were to have it on the code-behind of your custom `ComboBox`, this will defeat the purpose of `MVVM`, as the ComboBox is now dependent on the data-base. What you should strive for is to have 'loosely coupled' components, and let the `ViewModel` feed the data to the `View`.

You can do something like:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private _itemSource;
    public List<Entity> ItemSource 
    {
        get { return _itemSource; }
        private set 
        {
            _itemSource = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ItemSource");
        }
    }

    private void UpdateItemSource(int sampleId)
    {
        var newItems = SELECT itemCode, itemValue FROM UserDictionaries WHERE itemListCode = 'SAMPLE_ID';

        ItemSource = null;
        ItemSource = newItems;
    }
}
```

and then update your XAML to:

```
<ComboBox ItemSource="{Binding ItemSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem = "{Binding valueCode}" />
```

Comment: 1. probably I want to do something like "web combobox" with AJAX binding ;)
2. I'm a little scared working with ViewModel that contain 20 properties for combobox value and next 20 IDictionary for it ;) plus rest fields

Comment: why would the ViewModel have 20 properties for a combobox? you only need to have one property that is dynamic. you dont need a property for every ID

Comment: I have at least 20 combobox controls on one view plus other fields. (one property for value + one property for items lists) x 20 combobox controls = 40 properties on viewmodel.